# Dask task steam does not display a custom task given to `map_blocks`

Tags: dask, dashboard, python-xarray

I have written a function named `nd_rmmeh` and passed it to `dask.array.Array.map_blocks`.
The task runs and completes normally but does not show on task stream on dashboard.
This is despite the fact that it does show on task "graph" and task "progress" as seen in the picture below:

[image]

I did mouse over the boxes and did not find any `nd_rmmeh` labels.
The timing of `nd_rmmeh` do coincides with when empty (white) sections of task stream appears.
However, I couldn't see how it is actually run from the dashboard.
**I am interested in checking whether the `nd_rmmeh` release GIL enough to be run as threads instead of processes.**
I have a suspicion that it doesn't by looking at `htop` task manager.

For context, here is how I call `map_blocks`:

```python
da.copy(
    deep = False,
    data = da.data.map_blocks(
        nd_rmmeh,
        dtype = np.float,
        meta = da.data,
        # the rest is some key word arguments to nd_rmmeh ... omitted
    ),
)
```

I can not recall why I use `` instead of `xarray.map_blocks`,
but it feels like that shouldn't matter.

---

**So the questions is:**

- why task stream doesn't display the custom function and what could be done to fix it.

Comment: Functions passed to `map_blocks` should show up in the task stream, are you able to share a minimal reproducer? The white spaces in the task stream mean the workers aren't doing anything; you can learn more about the dashboard [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/diagnostics-distributed.html).